# DIV on the left side with flexible width but on the right side close to other DIV

Tags: css, html

i have a site with a fixed width (960px) and i want to add a row that is always on the left but always on the right side close to another. how to do this with CSS? the problem is that the extra row has to have a flexible width AND has to be always on the left side of the screen but the right end has to end where the other (content) container ends on the right.

[image]

Comment: lots of ways to accomplish this... Why don't you show us what you have so far

Comment: as @Reinder said, best way to get help on here is to post what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use js

- 1) Wait windows load.
- 2) launch the script when the user resize the    windows.
- [My codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/yLAnk)

HTML

```
<div id="red">coucou</div>
<div id="green">coucou</div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#red {width:1100px;margin:auto;background:red;height:100px;}

#green {background:green;height:100px;}
```

JS

```
window.onload=resize;


window.onresize= resize;

function resize(){

var larg =window.innerWidth ;
var largdiv= document.getElementById('red').offsetWidth  ;



var vava =  ( larg - largdiv ) / 2 + largdiv;
 //alert (vava);
document.getElementById('green').style.width = vava+"px";



}
```

Comment: Have you test my answer ?

Comment: thanks this works well, i thought there must be a way without JS butt ... okay. big thanks!